# Nomenclature of a tertiary amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

[image: N,N,3-trimethylpentan-3-amine]

What is the name of the amine shown above? Is it **N,N dimethyl (1-methyl-1-ethyl propane amine)**?

Comment: Related: [Amine Nomenclature – When to use “N”](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44349/7951)

Answer (score 4):

You have correctly identified the given compound as amine. Amines can be named in various ways. According to Subsection P-62.2.1.2 of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the preferred IUPAC names (PINs) are formed by using systematic substitutive nomenclature. Primary amines are systematically named by adding the suffix ‘amine’ to the name of the parent hydride; secondary and tertiary amines are named by the same method with further *N*-substitution (see Subsection P-62.2.2.1).

When there is a choice among acyclic parent hydrides, a principal chain must be chosen. The first relevant criterion in this case provides that the principal chain has the greater number of skeletal atoms; i.e., the principal chain is the longest chain (see Subsections P-44.3 and P-44.3.2).

In this case, the longest chain has five carbon atoms; i.e. the unmodified parent hydride is ‘pentane’.

Addition of the suffix ‘amine’ and the corresponding locant to the name of the parent hydride yields the name ‘pentan-3-amine’.

Finally, the substituent prefix ‘methyl’, the multiplicative prefix ‘tri’, and the corresponding locants are added to express substitution by three methyl groups, which yields the name ‘*N*,*N*,3-trimethylpentan-3-amine’ (note that ‘*N*’ is lower than ‘3’).

[image: N,N,3-trimethylpentan-3-amine]

Comment: there is an ethyl group present

Comment: @Pi5 When your structure includes “1-ethylpropane”, the longest chain actually is “pentane”.