# Name this amine

Tags: nomenclature, amines

Consider the following two amines:

[image]

I've been given the name for the second amine as N,N-dimethylamino-2-propane.

Can this same approach be used to name the first amine? If so, I think its name would be N-methylmethyl-2-amino-2-propane. Is this correct?

Comment: Related: [Nomenclature of Amines](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47777/7951)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Short Answer

The name you list does correspond to the first compound shown under the naming scheme you were given for the second compound, however last I checked the IUPAC scheme recommends "N,N-dimethyl-**2-propanamine**" not "N,N-dimethyl**amine-2-propane**" if you want to be really strict about it.

## A More Realistic Look at Naming

Putting all that aside, *you'll not often see simple substituted amines referred to this way by chemists*. IUPAC naming in general is useful for unambiguously naming large, tricky compounds but for smaller garden-variety ones it's often seen as unnecessarily cumbersome.

The IUPAC scheme names amines in reference to the longest carbon chain (e.g. "N,N-dimethyl-2-**propanamine**"). The more common scheme for amines with relatively simple substituents is to name them in reference to the *amine group* instead (e.g. "dimethyl isopropyl **amine**").

This is similar to the common-name schemes for most other rotationally symmetric functional groups. In general, they're formatted:

[***substituents**, alphabetical if you're a pedant*] followed by [***type of compound***]

For example, the compound consisting of a methyl group and an ethyl group attached to an **ether**, **ketone**, or **sulfide** would be called "methyl ethyl **ether**", "methyl ethyl **ketone**", or "methyl ethyl **sulfide**" respectively.

Finally returning to the example you've given, the first compound would most commonly be referred to as "methyl tert-butyl amine" and the second compound would be called "dimethyl isopropyl amine".

Comment: _“… however last I checked the IUPAC scheme recommends …”_ – Apparently that was before 1993 since you are still using IUPAC nomenclature from 1979. The current recommendations are from 2013.