# Naming a tri-substituted amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

Just came across this couldn't decide how to name it, anyone think they can give it a go?

$\hspace{7cm}$[image: amine]

Comment: Related: [Amine Nomenclature – When to use “N”](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44349/7951) and [Nomenclature of Amines](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47777/7951)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *N*-ethyl-*N*-methylpropan-2-amine. The base of this amine is propan-2-amine, and the nitrogen is substituted with an ethyl (*N*-ethyl) and a methyl (*N*-methyl) group.