# What does the "N" in N-nitrosoamine mean/stand for?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What does the "N" in N-nitrosoamine mean/stand for?  Also, if the functional group is connected to a benzene ring what do I call it?

Comment: An older review article: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-1979-0101.ch001

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/amine-nomenclature-when-to-use-n

Comment: @Mithoron Related, agreed, but not duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "N" means that the nitroso group ($\ce{-NO}$) is attached to the amine nitrogen.

So, for example, in [*N-nitrosomorpholine*](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/n7382?lang=en&region=US) the nitroso group is attached to the nitrogen atom of the saturated, heterocyclic morpholine ring:

[image: N-nitrosomorpholine]

You could never have an "N-nitroso" group attached to a plain benzene ring, since there is no nitrogen atom in a benzene ring for the "N-" prefix to refer to.

In general, though, you would name aromatic nitroso compounds in the same way as you would those with any other substituent like 'chloro-' or 'nitro-'. For example, the following compound would is named [*nitrosobenzene*](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/n24609?lang=en&region=US):

[image: Nitrosobenzene]

Answer (score 2):

A [nitroso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitroso) group is a nitrogen double bonded to an oxygen (think carbonyl). When that nitroso group is attached to an amine, it is an [*N*-nitrosoamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrosamine). We add the *N*- designation so we know that the nitroso group is bonded to the nitrogen of the amino group as opposed to somewhere else on what is presumably an organic molecule.